# ¿Cómo puedo crear dominios con restricciones de longitud y su valor contenido?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo problemas para comprender la estructuración de un código con el propósito de añadir restricciones como de tamaño, y de valores contenidos dentro de campos mediante dominios.

Como por ejemplo, si quisiera hacer un dominio que solo contenga 9 dígitos, con valores del 0 al 9.

Entiendo la estructura de la creación del dominio, más no la restricción en sí, o qué palabras se utilizarían para implementarlas.

```
create domain "cptype" as varchar(9)
check (value ~ '^\d{0-9}$');
```

Ese es el código que intenté implementar

Answer (score 0):

para eso puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
CREATE DOMAIN tudominio AS VARCHAR(9)
CHECK(VALUE ~ E'^[0-9]*$')
```

Comment: Gracias! Me funciona perfecto. Podría ser tan amable de decirme como puedo buscar información respecto a qué es lo que hace cada caracter dentro del check? como el ~, E, ', ^ y demás.

Comment: ~ operador de coincide con la expresión regular,
E' caracter de escape de PostgreSQL,
^ Inicio de regex,
$ Fin de regex,
* Coincide con lo anterior cero o más veces,
[ ] Un carácter o rango de caracteres